# Ruby on Rails open source Social App on GitHub

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github

I am starting with Ruby on Rails, finishing the tutorials on railstutorials.org. I would like to start to evolve trying to code something related to social behaviours, and i was wondering if someone on here knows any open source already done project on GitHub related to the next characteristics:

- users that post their 'profile' (name, photo, memo, etc) as resources
- users that sign up to be 'friends' of the users that post resources
- sign up process by email/pass
- using connectors (OATH2) for facebook or twitter to sign up

i know that RoR already offers all the framework needed to build this characteristics, but i would like to study a real project already done, because there are lots of knowledge that cant be learn though tutorials, like Design database Models.

thank you very much for your support and time

Answer (score 4):

Rails3: https://github.com/ging/social_stream "Social Stream, a core for building social network websites." Very current, being maintained today.  Generator approach that I like.

Rails2: https://github.com/insoshi/insoshi  Older and not being actively maintained.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to have a look at Diaspora (probably a bit too much to start with), Authlogic, [OmniAuth](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth), [Koala](https://github.com/arsduo/koala) and the like - plus possible related Railscasts to walk you through it. Good luck and have fun :)

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at [diaspora](https://github.com/diaspora/diaspora). May not be a beginners project, though.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to go through the learning app that's built in the free [Rails Book 3 Tutorial Site](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book).  The app that you build there literally goes over all of the things you want to do except for the Twitter / Facebook integration toward the end, but that's easy enough to integrate once you're aware of the basics.

Answer (score 0):

Check git for RailsSpace its a Social Network from a tutorial.

Many people (like myself) rebuildet it under Rails 3.

RailsSpace rocks for learning.

Btw. get the tutorial book, its good ;-)